# Specific CSS file when the screen is at a certain width

Tags: css, user-interface, web, styling

I want to organise my code so it's easier to read and put the styling of certain devices in separate files as such:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 599px)" href="assets\css\phone-main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="assets\css\tablet-main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1000px)" href="assets\css\pc-main.css">
```

But the problem I have is that it's not working, did I do it right or do I need to rewrite it a little?

Comment: It's likely that the path to the files could be incorrect, do you get any console messages saying the files cannot be found?
Could you share some example HTML and CSS that you are expecting to be applied?

Comment: The path to the file is correct, I don't get any error messages in the console.

Comment: The href's value looks wrong. It's an url to a resource, use forwardslash `/`.

Comment: Would you please tell us what you get in the console tab?

Answer (score 0):

Have a good day!

I shall say, that whether you're file is local or not, you should use `/` (fore slash) for `src` or `href` attributes in HTML; if you're file is local, then the browser will automatically convert `/` to `\`.

Simply change backslashes to forelashes and you're good to go.

Comment: This wont work... any other solutions?